# change firefox os update channel does not work

Tags: firefox-os

I've got a firefox os flame phone.
I installed the version 2.2 following this guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Phone_guide/Flame/Updating_your_Flame four days ago.
Now I'm trying to change the update channel to the nightly, I followed the guide on the same website, everything seems to went smooth but after my phone rebooted nothing has changed. It seems that I did everything right but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanksv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to change the update channel inside the developer menu. Please scroll down there to the end. The is the update channel, at my phone "nightly-b2g37" for Firefox OS 2.2 and the URL of the update server.